# Disable GDM suspend on lock screen

Tags: gnome3, gdm3

I'm using Arch Linux + GNOME3 on desktop, and when the system starts or the user logs out, `gdm` displays the login screen for about 20 seconds and then turns off the display (although the computer is still running). Is it possible to disable this? I want the monitor to keep displaying the login screen "forever". I couldn't find any way to configure this.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That's because of the `idle-delay` setting. To change it you'll have to alter the corresponding `dconf` key (and do that as the `gdm` user):

1. switch to a `VT` (e.g. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd>), login as *root* and run:

   ```
   su - gdm -s /bin/sh
   ```

   to switch user to `gdm`.
2. then run:

   ```
   export $(dbus-launch)
   ```

   and set idle delay to `0` (which translates to *never*):

   ```
   GSETTINGS_BACKEND=dconf gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.session idle-delay 0
   ```

   run `exit` or hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to return to *root* account.
3. reboot your machine or restart the display manager:

   ```
   systemctl restart gdm
   ```

Answer (score 11):

Just as an expansion to [don_crissti's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/361275/283549):

Step 2 didn't work for me. I am on Gnome/gdm 3.28 and I don't have `org.gnome.desktop.session`, but this one worked for me:

```
GSETTINGS_BACKEND=dconf gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-ac-type 'nothing'
```

Comment: On Debian, you can set it up in `/etc/gdm/greeter.dconf-defaults`.

Comment: more recently, `/etc/gdm3/greeter.dconf-defaults` is the file

Answer (score 2):

Edit `/etc/gdm3/greeter.dconf-defaults` and customize this section to your will.

I set the `sleep-inactive-ac-timeout` to zero and the `sleep-inactive-ac-type` to "nothing".

```
# Automatic suspend
# =================
[org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/power]
# - Time inactive in seconds before suspending with AC power
#   1200=20 minutes, 0=never
sleep-inactive-ac-timeout=0
# - What to do after sleep-inactive-ac-timeout
#   'blank', 'suspend', 'shutdown', 'hibernate', 'interactive' or 'nothing'
# sleep-inactive-ac-type='suspend'
sleep-inactive-ac-type='nothing'
# - As above but when on battery
# sleep-inactive-battery-timeout=1200
# sleep-inactive-battery-type='suspend'
```

Then reload gdm:

```bash
systemctl reload gdm
systemctl reload gdm3
```

I did not get to make it with the existing answers. There is a comment about this file; for me it was the answer.

Answer (score 2):

### Fedora, 2023-05

#### 1. Add a specific dconf profile for the gdm user

Check /etc/dconf/profile/gdm exists. If not then add it. It contains a `user-db` line for the user settings, and then `system-db` and `file-db` lines for defaults:

```
user-db:user
system-db:gdm
file-db:/usr/share/gdm/greeter-dconf-defaults
```

Note that there can be multiple `system-db:` lines, so a enterprise environment like that at Example Corporation might choose to use a line like `system-db: examplecorp-gdm` for the corporate wide-settings for GDM (say setting the Example Corp logo and a login screen message equivalent to /etc/issue). Thus leaving the more typical `system-db:gdm` available for use by the laptop user's customisation tools.

#### 2. Add a new directory to contain the new gdm settings

Check /etc/dconf/db/gdm.d/ exists. If not then create the directory.

#### 3. Add the new gdm settings into a file

Add the file /etc/dconf/db/gdm.d/01-local-power containing

```
[org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/power]
sleep-inactive-ac-type='nothing'
sleep-inactive-ac-timeout=0
```

If you wish to alter other settings then use `dconf-editor` to find the setting and its allowed values, then take the "schema" value, replacing `.` with `/`, and use that as the section heading in the configuration file (the "org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/power" in the example above). For values which are strings, enclose the string in single quote `'`.

Some other common settings for the gdm user are:

```
[org/gnome/login-screen]
logo='/usr/local/share/pixmaps/examplecorp-logo.svg'
banner-message-enable=true
banner-message-text='Example Corporation, to Lorem Ipsum and beyond!'
[org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/power]
power-button-action='interactive'
```

#### 4. Build the dconf database from the files

`sudo dconf update` then check for the presence of /etc/dconf/db/gdm.

Answer (score 1):

Adjusting the following via the `dconf-editor` might help fine-tune the sleep related settings:

```
sleep-inactive-ac-timeout
sleep-inactive-ac-type
sleep-inactive-battery-timeout
sleep-inactive-battery-type
```

Worth a try, in my case it was *the* way to get the machine to stay awake during periods of inactivity.

Comment: sed -i "s/# sleep-inactive-ac-timeout=1200/sleep-inactive-ac-timeout=0/" /etc/gdm3/greeter.dconf-defaults
sed -i "s/# sleep-inactive-battery-timeout=1200/sleep-inactive-battery-timeout=0/" /etc/gdm3/greeter.dconf-defaults

systemctl restart gdm3

Answer (score 1):

Ive figured it out. Search up "inactive" on dconfig and change what to do when person is inactive to turn off to nothing. Make sure you do it to both of them because there is two.

Comment: I could sent a screenshot to show where, but I dont know how to send it on this website

Comment: Click the [edit] link under your answer. In the editor there is an add picture button. See [How do you add a screenshot image to your Stack Overflow post?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/344851/4424636) or better still [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/75491/280335)